# How do you wait for an application to close in OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I am using the code below to check if an application is running and close it. Can someone provide an example of how to request an application calose and wait for it to close before proceeding?

```
+ (BOOL)isApplicationRunningWithName:(NSString *)applicationName {
    BOOL isAppActive = NO;
    NSDictionary *aDictionary;
    NSArray *selectedApps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];

    for (aDictionary in selectedApps) {
        if ([[aDictionary valueForKey:@"NSApplicationName"] isEqualToString: applicationName]) {
            isAppActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isAppActive;
}

+ (void)stopApplication:(NSString *)pathToApplication {
    NSString *appPath = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication:pathToApplication];
    NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:appPath] bundleIdentifier];
    NSArray *selectedApps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:identifier];
    // quit all
    [selectedApps makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(terminate)];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to observe the `terminated` property of each running application. This way, you'll get notified when each application terminates, without having to poll.

Comment: That sounds like a clean way to do it, I will see if I can figure out how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to periodically call `isApplicationRunningWithName` on a timer, and wait until that function returns `NO`.

Comment: Would you have a code sample that might show how I would accomplish that?

Comment: I don't have a code sample handy, but I would use [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and set up a repeating timer to call one of your methods. From there, you can find out whether the application is still running and either continue waiting or cancel the timer and continue.

Answer (score 0):

The commandline [`timelimit`](http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/) will let you send a close signal to an app, wait x seconds, then kill it (or send any other signal you like, kill is -9) if hasn't obeyed the "warning" signal.

(Note: I haven't tried compiling it on Mac, but I believe it's fairly POSIX-compliant code and not Linux-specific as it runs on BSD and others.)

Comment: That may be useful when doing this as the user, but the question is about how to do it inside an application.

Comment: Nothing is easier than programmatically launching a command line app. Just popen or fork and exec.

Comment: It's not just ease. timelimit may work fine for running a command-line tool, but applications must be launched using Launch Services. Otherwise, you're likely to end up with multiple copies of the app running (LS will normally activate an already-running process instead) and the app will be subject to your sandbox instead of its own.

Comment: I didn't know that - thanks for clarifying. My OS X development is strictly limited to libraries and command line utilities.